# Arch Linux - Is it possible to instruct pacman to install certain packages into a specific directory?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I want to install a set of software organized into directories at the root level.

Is there any method in which I can use pacman to install certain packages into a directory of my choosing?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that's possible, by specifying a different root location,

> -r, --root  Specify an alternative installation root (default is /). This should not be used as a way to install software into
>   /usr/local instead of /usr. This option is used if you want to install
>   a package on a temporary mounted partition that is "owned" by another
>   system. NOTE: if database path or logfile are not specified on either
>   the command line or in pacman.conf(5), their default location will be
>   inside this root path.

Comment: What should I do about the dbpath with that method?

Comment: @TerryChia you want to alternate where pacman stores information of installed packages?

Comment: No, but I got an error: failed to initialize alpm library (could not find or read directory), which from some googling - i assume to be an error with the dbpath.

Comment: @TerryChia Hmm, I think the '-r' is used to install a new system just like what the Installation Media does, I don't have a Arch at hand right now, will try it later. If this doesn't work, you're going to modify the PKGBUILD file, the XXX_install function defined there. (A prefix can be specified for most software based on autogen)

Answer (score -1):

I know what you wanna do. You want something like running an executable with in a container "if it is" to avoid damaging the system.

Solution: link needed directories by `pacman` like `/var` using:

```
ln -s /var .
```

Use `-s` for soft linking

Run pacman with `-r .`:

```
sudo pacman -r . -S package
```

and you will be fine.